# If I import a superclass, do I need to import it's subclass too?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, import

I imported the `java.util.Calendar` class and it's `getInstance()` method returns an instance of a subclass object of itself which in my case is of type `java.util.GregorianCalendar`. 
However why do I only need to import `java.util.Calendar` for this to work if I'm also using in this program `java.util.GregorianCalendar` when `getInstance()` is called?

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: You import what you actually use in **your** code. If implementation needs something else it will import it.

Comment: @PM77-1 Since both classes are in the same package `java.util`, the implementation of `Calendar` won't need an import statement to refer to `GregorianCalendar`.

Comment: just to add, you could `import java.util.*` which imports all the classes from that package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, `import` declarations are purely for name resolution. You don't need to import `GregorianCalendar` because your code doesn't use the name `GregorianCalendar` to refer to anything. From the Java Language Specification ([§7.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5)):

> An import declaration allows a named type or a static member to be referred to by a simple name (§6.2) that consists of a single identifier.

Comment: Cleared up my doubt and more! Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Calendar` is an Abstract Class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Any class that extends (by implementing the abstract methods) the `Calendar` class is also a `Calendar`, that's why you can use the `GregorianCalendar` as a `Calendar`.

However, if you decided to use a specific  method from the `GregorianCalendar`, let's say: `setGregorianChange`, then you would need to change your code to import the 
`GregorianCalendar` as well as  change your `cal` variable to be of type `GregorianCalendar`

Comment: Strictly speaking, you could instead write the fully qualified name `java.util.GregorianCalendar` to use it without importing it.